# remove [canadian-law] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

should we remove the [canadian-law](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canadian-law) tag that was created per request of [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/129215/41381) question?

I think it just opens the door to create too many different [country-law] tags that aren't that useful. I think [law] is good enough for legal questions on Pogrammers.SE since every question about legal issues more or less comes with an ask a lawyer anyway disclaimer, and legal questions while allowed aren't a primary focus of this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, I agree. I don't think the tag makes any sense in the long term.

We certainly don't want to encourage more general legal questions after [we already reduced the scope in the FAQ from "software law" to "software licensing"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/are-software-law-questions-off-topic-here).

Update: I went ahead and removed the tag from the question. The tag will disappear from the site in a day or so.

Comment: I think [this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/are-software-law-questions-off-topic-here) prompted the faq change...

Comment: @YannisRizos That's the one. Thanks!